# Can this piece of VB.NET cause a memory increase / memory leak?

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, sonarqube, code-inspection

I'm facing a memory increase, looking like a memory leak, in a VB.NET process (see my latest other questions).

Now I've seen that the memory usage increases every time this piece of code is executed. I've subscribed to SonarCube in order to help investigation, but I don't have the license yet, so I need to check this manually (but I don't know VB.NET that well, and as far as I can judge, .NET takes care of the memory management, so there shouldn't be any memory leak possible).

Hereby my source code:

```
Private Sub ExecuteTask(ByVal task As Task)
    Dim taskToExecute As Tasks.ITask = ...(task.TaskName) 
        ' taskToExecute gets retrieved from a dictionary
    Try
        If taskToExecute Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("No task found with name :" + task.TaskName)
        End If

        If taskToExecute.Execute() = True Then
            RaiseEvent TaskExecuted(taskToExecute)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent TaskFailed(taskToExecute)
    End Try
End Sub
```

(As far as I can judge from the logs, the task execution is successful.)

Thanks in advance (or is this a question for the Code Review site?)

Comment: It's very unlikely that there's an actual memory leak in VB code. A memory leak is literally memory allocated that is no longer accessible and cannot be deallocated. Allocating memory and simply not deallocating is not a memory leak. That might happen in .NET if you are allocating a lot of memory and the system doesn't have a chance to reclaim it, e.g. repeated creation of `Image` objects. There doesn't look to be anything in the code you posted that would be problematic. We don't know what your `ITask` objects actually are though. Does memory go up if the tasks do nothing?

Comment: Does your task type include `IDisposable`?  `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` does, but it looks like you're using your own custom type.  If so, you need to make sure you're `Dispose`-ing of the objects when they go out of use.  You may also want to do some memory profiling to see if your objects aren't getting collected after they go out of use, which might happen if they live long enough to go into a different generation in the GC.

Comment: @Craig: you might be on to something here: I indeed don't see an `IDisposable` interface the task inherits from. But if that is the case, then why did this source run without problems during more than 10 years?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to have `IDisposable`, I just though that the fact that the framework task type does so is instructive.  I was looking at it more from the point of view that a common issue is not calling `Dispose` (either indirectly through a `Using` block or directly) when using something that implements `IDisposable`, rather than from the point of view that the task type isn't implementing it but should.